# How to initialize new list using elements from another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have the list with some static elements

```
list = ["1", "2", "3"]
```

and I get the list outside. So I want to use it for initializing

I tried to do something like this but it doesn't work. I understand that I can initialize list in first line and then append second list. But the question is about how to do it in one line

```
list = ["1", "2", "3"].append(elem for elem in outside_list)
```

Comment: What happened, and what result do you want to get. It's hard to read your mind when we don't agree on what your example should do.

Comment: Are you expecting in-place extension, or a new object, with the original staying the same?

Comment: MCI answered totally what I wanted

Comment: That doesn't make your question any easier to understand. Please fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list = ["1","2","3"] + [elem for elem in outside_list]`
or simply
`list = ["1","2","3"] + outside_list`

Comment: Better yet, `list.extend(outside_list)`. In place operation.